# Generating, Evaluating, then Re-generating Random Numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, function, random

I need to generate random values for a few variables. And then, if those values meet certain characteristics, I need to trash them and re-generate (re-define the value of the variable?).

I probably need to do this with a function but I'm just learning those and not sure how to escape the "locality" of variables created in a function (I'll need to call them later in the script).

So let's say I have:

```
x = rand(1...9)
y = rand(1...9)
z = rand(1...9)
```

Afterward I need something like

```
if x - y - z < 0
then **start over** until x - y - z > 0
end
```

It seems like this must have a "simple" solution that I just don't have the experience/knowledge to see. Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: If you find any of the answers helpful please consider selecting the one you liked best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    x = rand(1...9)
    y = rand(1...9)
    z = rand(1...9)

while x - y - z > 0
    x = rand(1...9)
    y = rand(1...9)
    z = rand(1...9)
end

puts "x: #{x}, y: #{y}, z: #{z}"
```

More generic way may be using method like this:

```
def generate 
    x = rand(1...9)
    y = rand(1...9)
    z = rand(1...9)
    [x,y,z]
end 
x,y,z = generate()

while x - y - z > 0
    x,y,z = generate()
end

puts "x: #{x}, y: #{y}, z: #{z}"
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a number of patterns in programming, and Ruby in particular, that you'll see time and time again. This *generate-and-verify-on-fail-redo* type pattern is fairly common, and common enough Ruby has a `begin ... end while (cond)` structure for it.

One thing that's working against you here is having three variables. This violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) which is essential to having organized code. When dealing with more than "one" thing, consider using a data structure like an array.

Taking all that into account here's a simple approach:

```
def random_values(count = 3)
  begin
    values = Array.new(count) { rand(1...9) }
  end while (values.inject(&:-) <= 0)

  values
end
```

This keeps generating lists until you find one that meets your criteria. The `inject` call is a quick way of performing the subtraction on the numbers in a particular set by iterating through the list and subtracting one element from the next, then using that result in the subsequent loop.

The `Array` constructor is given two arguments, one is the number of elements to pre-allocate to it, the second is a block that defines how those elements should be produced. This is a quick way of making a N length array of random values.

Now a slightly more Ruby way of doing this is to define a generator of random number sets:

```
random_values = Enumerator.new do |y|
  loop do
    y << Array.new(3) { rand(1...9) }
  end
end
```

This allows you to apply the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html) library to the problem and `find` the first entry matching your criteria. Here you can expand the variables in the array within this local test block to keep the code simple:

```
first = random_values.find do |x, y, z|
  x - y - z > 0
end
```

The advantage of this approach is you can chain things together and get things like this:

```
selection = random_values.lazy.select do |x, y, z|
  x - y - z > 0
end.first(10)
```

This will "lazy" enumerate arrays, that is it will produce them on-demand instead if running that loop until completion, and will pull out the first 10 that match and save those in an array called `selection`.

Comment: Why not use `while values.inject(&:-) <= 0`?

Comment: Thanks very much tadman. So, later in the script, outside this function, I can call those values from the array? i.e. puts values[0]  or  puts  values[0] + values[1]?

Comment: @pjs Actually that's a better way of doing it, I'll change it. Thanks!

Comment: @old_dog_new_tricks - Outside the function they won't be called `values`, they'll be called whatever variable name you assigned the function return:  `foo = random_values` would give you the values in `foo`.

Comment: Perhaps generalize to pass a proc or block that evaluates the condition that must be satisfied by the random numbers.

Comment: @old_dog_new_tricks You can expand the results if you want like `x, y, z = random_values` and you'll get whatever names you want. By default you'll get an array if you specify only one value on the *left-side* of the assignment.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I put in an example using an Enumerator which makes the validation logic a lot easier to inline.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You should at least give people a hint about [`arity`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Proc.html#method-i-arity) otherwise that will seem like dark magic.

Comment: Shhh! They should be able to find it. Extra points for an answer that doesn't use the method mentioned by tadman.

Comment: Readers, here's an exercise for you: construct a method `doit` such that `doit(1..9) { |x,y,z| x-y-z > 0 } #=> [9, 3, 3]; doit(1..9) { |x,y| x-y > 0 } #=> [6, 4]`. 
.